# isSetSupported test passes, but API is not available and throws ApiNotFound error

Tags: excel, office-js

The method [`suspendApiCalculationUntilNextSync`](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/excel/application.md#suspendapicalculationuntilnextsync) is part of the Excel API 1.6 according to the documentation.

My current setup is a Excel 2016 for Mac v15.40. When I run my project, the test below passes, but as `context.sync()` does its job, I get the error `ApiNotFound`.

```
if (Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported("ExcelApi", 1.6)) {
  context.workbook.application.suspendApiCalculationUntilNextSync();
}
```

Is `suspendApiCalculationUntilNextSync` really from 1.6?

This code works normally with Excel for Windows. There is an issue here, because both Mac and Windows Excel "says" they support 1.6, but only the Windows version has the method implemented.

Comment: Thanks for reporting, the team is investing the issue now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was fixed. I just verified the `suspendApiCalculationUntilNextSync` API in Mac, it's not repro in my side. please validate, kindly create a new issue or report it via [office-js issue](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues) in github if you still observe `ApiNotFound` error

Comment: I can't validate it because I don't have an (easy) Mac setup anymore. I'll mark it as answer since it has been a long time, and thanks for fixing the issue!